# Creating the simplest possible mailing list in libre office

Tags: libreoffice, mailing-list

I want to create a mailing list in Libre Office that I can use to print address labels.  I need no other functionality whatsoever.  I know that Write has a format for the labels I plan to use.  What is the absolutely simplest way to achieve this?  No bells, no whistles.

Comment: Hi Paul; if you use the Mail Merge Wizard from Tools; it takes you through; eg they say "    5. On the next step of the wizard, click the Select Address List button to check that you are using the correct address list. If you want to use an address block, select an address block type, match the data fields if necessary, and click Next." LibreOffice Help (F1key) covers it there too. This page may come at it from an angle that is more what you are describing: https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Printing_Address_Labels as always, Google may be your friend

Comment: What is the best tool to create the necessary database and table?  I'm confused because databases have so much functionality -- far too much for what I want to do.  Do I need to create a spreadsheet as well?

Comment: you are going to need to do some reading; to align your wishes with what LO can offer; eg https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/39045/how-do-i-create-a-database-of-contacts-for-basic-mailing-label-group-management/

Comment: Perhaps I should put my question differently.  I have the labels in a single column of a Calc spreadsheet.  Is there a way to print them in one of the Avery formats without creating a database?

Comment: thanks Paul; I suggest you join the LibreOffice forum https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/questions/ and I say that because the moderators of this Ubuntu forum will "hold" questions that are not directly ubuntu related; I find the LibreOffice folks very helpful; best wishes; if you get it all sorted, maybe leave a link back here to help

Answer (score 0):

Creating a spreadsheet with three columns is the simplest:

- Name
- Street Address
- City, State ZIP

Use the mail merge function to pull the data onto the Avery form.

If you need to sort by zip, state, or city, then make five colums instead of three:

- Name
- Street Address
- City
- State
- ZIP

More complex? Insert columns for address and/or c/o.  But KISS it: Keep It Simple, Sam!